# How to derive public generic class using less accessible parameter without inconsistent accessibility error?

Tags: c#

I have the class `ImplementationDetail` which I would like to keep internal, e.g.:

```
internal class ImplementationDetail
{
}
```

I have `GenericBaseClass` that uses its parameter privately, e.g.:

```
public class GenericBaseClass<T>
{
    private T useImplementationDetail;
}
```

And, I have a `Derived` class that specifies to use `ImplementationDetail`, e.g.:

```
public class DerivedClass: GenericBaseClass<ImplementationDetail>
{
}
```

This results in the error [CS0060 Inconsistent accessibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5732hs83.aspx); which is caused by `ImplementationDetail` being `internal` whereas `DerivedClass` is `public`.
How can I avoid the CS0060 compiler error while keeping `ImplementationDetail` `internal`?

Comment: Make `ImplementationDetail` public! You can't do anything else really as you are exposing that class outside of the unit it is in.

Comment: make `ImplementationDetail` an interface, and make the interface public.  If you have a public class of `T`, that `T` should be as accessible as the class.

Comment: No, make it protected and only derived classes can access.

Comment: @Botonomous still, he will not be able to specify it as generic parameter

Comment: @Kasper It's strange that implementation detail is exposed externally through a public *T* argument. Either it should be completely hidden, or, as Jonesopolis suggests, just an interface. And if it's an interface, you class shouldn't be generic at all, your `useImplementationDetail` should be of the interface type.

Comment: @galenus you're right, instead of constructing the `ImplementationDetail`-object in `GenericBaseClass` I can pass it in the constructor.  (`ImplementationDetail` implements a public generic interface).

Comment: Another option is to make the `ImplementationDetail` class `public` but make the constructor `internal`. It would be visible, but not usable (as in no instance can be created).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible.

You have to use a public interface or class.  See the comments of @DavidG, @Jonesopolis.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an internal class, use an interface.  Then use [explicit implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(v=vs.71).aspx) on the methods you want to keep private.  That way, they're never exposed.

Comment: Aren't explicit implementations exposed when the client uses the instance via the interface that defines these methods?